# Pokemon GO missing google sign up option

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently I downloaded Pokemon GO but when I try to sign up with google account,the option isn't there. Help please. I use a LG G2 mini

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't make a Google account in Pokemon GO](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275905/i-cant-make-a-google-account-in-pokemon-go)

Comment: @Yoshi24517 I'd close vote the other one instead, since this question has the better answer.

Answer (score 11):

Are you old enough to meet the legal age requirment for a google account? If not, then it will default to the Pokemon Trainer Club instead. (If age isn't a factor, try changing regions on your phone)

Comment: Thanks. I recently had the same problem. I answered the birthday incorrectly, and then promptly forgot about it.

Comment: Note that if you have incorrectly answered the birthday question you'll need to uninstall and reinstall the game. At least on iOS, as they seem to be storing that answer local.