# I can't make a Google account in Pokemon GO

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I can't make a Google account in Pokemon GO i can only make a Pokemon go trainer club account and on my phone that's not works... Are there someone whit the same problem or is it only me? What are I'm doing wrong and are there someone out there there can help me? I hear thousand of things about Pokemon GO and I will very very very like to play it, but I can't, plzz help me

Answer (score 1):

Simply create the google account outside Pokemon Go (on your device's browser for example), and then login in that new account when you open the Pokemon Go app.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that at times when the servers are being heavily utilized, it is extremely difficult to create accounts either with Google, or the Pokemon trainer club.

The only option is to wait until a time when the servers are calmer.

Answer (score -1):

You might be too young to play, just delete the app, download it again, change your age and make it something 13+

See if it works